# apt-get install -f seems to purge too much

Tags: apt, skype, dependencies

I've been trying to install skype to the 12.04 64bit.

Installing `ai32-libs` doesnt work at all (something about held packages and none of recommendations hasn't helped).

I've installed package somehow (`dpkg` probably), but it still doesnt work. But now something is broken with dependenses, and `install -f` causes purge of those packages:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
   linux-headers-3.2.0-37 python-routes libchm1 linux-headers-3.2.0-37-generic libpodofo0.9.0 python-cherrypy3 python-dnspython python-mechanize
   python-webob python-beautifulsoup python-cssutils libssl1.0.0: i386 zlib1g: i386
To remove them, use the «apt-get autoremove».
Will be installed the following additional packages:
   libssl1.0.0: i386 zlib1g: i386
The packages will be REMOVED:
   appmenu-qt calibre calibre-bin checkbox-qt intel-gpu-tools libdbusmenu-qt2 libdconf-qt0 libgl1-mesa-dri libqt4-dbus libqt4-declarative
   libqt4-designer libqt4-help libqt4-network libqt4-opengl libqt4-script libqt4-scripttools libqt4-sql libqt4-sql-sqlite libqt4-svg libqt4-xml
   libqt4-xmlpatterns libqtassistantclient4 libqtbamf1 libqtdee2 libqtgconf1 libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 libunity-2d-private0 libutouch-geis1 libva-x11-1
   libxcb-composite0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-xv0 lightdm pulseaudio-module-x11 python-qt4 qdbus qt-at-spi radeontool skype: i386 sni-qt
   ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-sso-client-qt ubuntuone-control-panel-qt unity-2d unity-2d-panel unity-2d-shell unity-2d-spread virtualbox-4.2 vlc xdiagnose
   xorg xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
NEW packages will be installed:
   libssl1.0.0: i386 zlib1g: i386i xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

Here is `apt-get check` output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  skype: i386: Depends: libasound2: i386 (> = 1.0.23) but it is not installed
               Depends: libqt4-dbus: i386 (> = 4:4.5.3) but it is not installed
               Depends: libqt4-network: i386 (> = 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
               Depends: libqt4-xml: i386 (> = 4:4.5.3) but it is not installed
               Depends: libqtcore4: i386 (> = 4:4.7.0 ~ beta1) but it is not installed
               Depends: libqtgui4: i386 (> = 4:4.8.0) but it is not installed
               Depends: libqtwebkit4: i386 (> = 2.2 ~ 2011week36) but it is not installed
               Depends: libx11-6: i386 but it is not installed
               Depends: libxext6: i386 but it is not installed
               Depends: libxss1: i386 but it is not installed
               Depends: libxv1: i386 but it is not installed
               Depends: libssl1.0.0: i386 but it is not installed
               Recommends: sni-qt: i386 but it is not installed
               Recommends: libasound2-plugins: i386 but it is not installed
```

What should I try? I don't want to uninstall that all.

Comment: @Braiam, done..

Answer (score 0):

This is me guessing, but you downloaded the old 32-bits skype deb package and tried to install with `dpkg -i` in a 64-bit system. I'm not going to ask you about that.

Now to solve your little problem, uninstall skype:

```
sudo apt-get remove skype
```

If that don't work then with `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg --remove skype
```

Then, either download the 64-bit skype package, or use the Ubuntu Partner repositories and install it:

```
wget http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
[...]
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install libasound2 libqt4-dbus libqt4-network libqt4-xml libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 libx11-6 libxext6 libxss1 libxv1 libssl1.0.0
sudo dpkg -i skype*.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

That should allow you to install skype with easy.

Comment: same thing :( . http://pastebin.com/KexJgLmT . And I have removeed skype:i386 .